# Module build error when running Vuetify with Sass

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, sass, vuetify.js

I am using Webpack with Vuetify and I get a SASS error when compiling.  My webpack config file is:

```
'use strict'

const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass|css)/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            // options: {
            //   implementation: require('sass'),
            //   fiber: require('fibers'),
            //   indentedSyntax: true // optional
            // },
            // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                fiber: require('fibers'),
                indentedSyntax: true // optional
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()]
};
```

The error I receive when building is:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-2!./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Expected newline.
  ╷
1 │ @charset "UTF-8";
  │                 ^
```

I'm convinced I must be missing some setting in the options for the style loaders somewhere, but I don't know what.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hey, yes you will have this kind of error because you support SASS and semicolons aren't allowed in the indented SASS syntax. You can use semicolons only if you use SCSS syntax.

For more Infos : https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#the-indented-syntax